How to use justify-content space between with css grid
I have a grid layout for my entire site that uses 12 columns
and I want to have 3 items with each taking 3 col and distribute the renaming space between them,
something like justify-content: space-between is css flex
I understand I can do that without css grid, was just wondering if
I can do that with css grid
I want to achieve something like this

html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item">3</div>
</div>

css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid__item {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightgreen;
}


That's not how a grid should be sued in the first place. Also a reason why Bootstrap despite the support still uses flexbox rather than grid for their grid.

You have to calculate the widths of the divs and then align them in grid-area places.
 width: calc((100vw - (10px * 11))/4);

10px is the gap, 11 is the number of gaps based on the number of columns, 4 is the 12 divided by the number of elements.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "a a a b b b b b b c c c";
  gap: 10px;
  //justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid__item {
  width: calc((100vw - (10px * 11))/4);
  /* 10px is the gap, 11 is the number of gaps based on the number of columns, 4 is the 12 divided by the number of elements */
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  grid-area: a;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-area: b;
  justify-self: center;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-area: c;
  justify-self: end;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item">3</div>
</div>




Paulie, the number 2 is not centered.

Edited to clarify

would it not be easier to let the cenetr element span 3 columns as well and then use an off-set of 50% column with by adding a margin-left

You're welcome to add your own answer but both are a little "hacky".
